# Swift - cannot replace some specific chars

Tags: ios, swift

I'm in trouble with replacing strings in Swift.
It seems there are some chars (e.g. "+") which cannot be replaced with "stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString".
Look at the example code below.
The result should be "hello_stackoverflow!", but the "+" cannot be replaced.
Do you have any ideas? Thanks.

```
    var mytext = "hello+world!"
    mytext = mytext.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("world", withString: "stackoverflow", options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range: nil);
    mytext = mytext.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("+", withString: "_", options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range: nil);
    println("\(mytext)")
```

result:
hello+stackoverflow!

Comment: Pass `0` instead of `NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `.RegularExpressionSearch` if you don't want it — `+` is a special character in [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/). You can just use

```
mytext = mytext.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("+", withString: "_")
```